# Parameter Expansion in Zsh vs Bash: what is the equivalent of "${VAR,,}"?

Tags: zsh, parameter-expansion

I am trying to perform [case modification](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#case_modification) with bash/zsh parameter expansion on macOS (11.4) and making some mistakes. Specifically, I want to take a variable that contains a string and turn it to snakecase (i.e.: from `This is a STRING` to `this_is_a_string`). I am taking baby steps and so far I am just trying to turn everything to lowercase and, as far as I understand it, the theory should work like this:

```sh
$ VAR="StRING"
$ echo "${VAR,,}" # turn the string characters to lowercase
string
```

This did not work at first, because macOS bash is the very much outdated 3.2.57. I installed the current version (5.1.8) with homebrew and it worked.

Still, this does not work with zsh (most recent version). I guess this happens because parameter expansion is different in zsh, am I right? Still, I cannot find any resourceful reference. I believe that zsh works a bit differently, more like `sed`. Sure, I could use `tr` and even `sed` itself, but I wanted to use parameter expansion.

Comment: See `man zshexpn` for all the different operations you can use with parameter expansion. (And more generally, `man zshall` to get an overview of all the various man pages documenting `zsh`.)

Comment: Are you asking how to do this in zsh, or do you want to do it in bash, or are you hoping for a solution that will work in both?

Comment: I was only looking for a solution in zsh (the documentation was not really clear to me and I could not find many tutorials online). But now I guess the safest way of doing that is exploiting `tr` or `sed` for compatibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Zsh, you can use [*expansion modifiers*](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers):

```sh
echo ${VAR:l}
## => string
```

To turn the string to upper case, you can use

```sh
echo ${VAR:u}
## => STRING
```

See an [online Zsh demo](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/zDHIVim4JMjTz12JKzU5I19BpRooZpVTi8wrreWCcTV8NIEicFmNUAj3/38A).

Or, you may use [*expansion flags*](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags):

```sh
echo ${(L)VAR}
## => string
echo ${(U)VAR}
## => STRING
```

Comment: And `${(L)VAR}` and `${(U)VAR}`.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern to convert to lowercase using zsh AND parameter expansion is by using the `L` flag.

Using your example:

```sh
> VAR="StRING"
> echo ${(L)VAR}
```

However I'm not sure how portable it will be between bash and zsh.

Comment: It won't be portable at all. The two shells use two completely different syntaxes for this.